# enable htaccess apcahe on ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I have an apache server on ubuntu where i have a virtual host that points to my site. Problem is my htaccess not functional.

In my apache2.conf file i have something like

```
   <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

    <Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

if i change AllowOverride for "www" directory htaccess is functional but i get 403 forbidden error. please guide me what i am doing wrong.

regards.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set AllowOverride to all like this.

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

After that if you are facing forbidden error then probably you have error in htaccess file. Remove the code in htaccess file then start writing code block by block. By this you can debug error in htaccess file. For more info, you can have a look on this.

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/429869/is-this-a-correct-way-to-enable-htaccess-in-apache-2-4-7-on-ubuntu-12-04#answer-429931

Comment: I tried that already, by removing all the code and blank htacess it still gives error.